# DevExpress - Winforms - How do I float a widget outside the main window?

Tags: winforms, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I am using a sample code as mentioned at https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument114785 however I cannot make it float outside the main window as it does in the DevExpress Sample Demo "Free Float in Widget View"

Answer (score 0):

Apparently float outside window is defined via ItemDragStyle property

```
view.FreeLayoutProperties.ItemDragStyle = ItemDragStyle.DockingHints;
```

It looks like a bad API name, i see in WPF library it is better named as `DockLayoutManager.FloatingMode`.